in heroku, set environment variable to the value of DATABASE_URL
I think I've seen this question asked, but I can't find an answer.
I'm trying to install Metabase in a Docker container on Heroku.  Metabase wants an environment variable called MB_DB_CONNECTION_URI.  I want to just make that an "alias" for DATABASE_URL, so that when Heroku changes my connection string, things "just work."
Is this possible?

The Heroku CLI command addons:attach like the below would be of a help (replace the postgresql-abcdefg-12345 with the actual add-on name for your Heroku Postgres add-on):
heroku addons:attach postgresql-abcdefg-12345 --as MB_DB_CONNECTION

which would create and alias config var MB_DB_CONNECTION_URL. Unfortunately, the postfix _URL cannot be changed to _URI.
If Metabase cannot be modified to refer to MB_DB_CONNECTION_URL, configuring the Docker image to run a script like the below would work so that the environment variable is set every time the dyno starts.
export MB_DB_CONNECTION_URI=$DATABASE_URL

